# Angular ng-repeat directive issue with indeterminate amount of child objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with tree structured data.  The parent could have indeterminate amount of children and those children can have indeterminate amount of children and etc..  I have the JSON format in a nice nested structure.  However, when I build my angular template, how can I account for the indeterminacy?

Here is my attempt:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in manhole.data">

  <div ng-if="object.object"
       ng-repeat="childObject in object.object">

    <div ng-if="childObject.object"
         ng-repeat="childChildObject in childObject.object"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

So far this will only work for tree structure with max depth = 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can't with just ng-repeat.

Your best chance is to use a directive that nests itself wheter it finds a new child.

This is an old directive i made to create menus with an indeterminate number of sublevels, i hope it can be of help to you: http://plnkr.co/edit/8JL0Op?p=preview
there's probably a better way to do it (i did this when i was still learning Angular) but i think you can get the idea from here

code:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
 $scope.name = "Test";
 $scope.values = [
   {"name":"test1"},
   {"name":"test2", children:[
     {"name":"test21"}, 
     {"name":"test22"}, 
     {"name":"test23", children:[
     {"name":"test231"}, 
     {"name":"test232"}, 
     {"name":"test233"}
   ]}
   ]},
   {"name":"test3"},
   ];
}]);

angular.module('app').directive('hyMenu', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{
        menuList:"=hyMenu"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {},
    templateUrl: function(element ,attrs) {
        if(attrs.sub=="true"){
            return 'hy-sub.htm';
        } else {
            return 'hy-menu.htm';
        }
    }
  };
}).directive('hyElement', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, menuCtrl) {
      if(!scope.elem.children){
                scope.elem.children=[];
        }
        if (scope.elem.children.length > 0){
          console.log(scope.elem.children); 
            element.append("<ul hy-menu='elem.children' data-sub='true'></ul>");
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    },
    templateUrl:  function(element, attrs) {
        return 'hy-elem.htm';
    }
  };
});
```

Templates:

index.htm

```
<div class="hy-menu" hy-menu="values"></div>
```

hy-menu.htm

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="elem in menuList" hy-element="elem"></li>
</ul>
```

hy-sub.htm

```
<li ng-repeat="elem in menuList" hy-element="elem"></li>
```

hy-elem.htm

```
{{elem.name}}
```